# Absolute Jumps Within Shared Object Code Unix

Tags: c, unix, linker, dynamic-linking

I have a question regarding the handling and interpretation of shared libraries.

Suppose, I build a shared object from foo.c using the command:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o libfoo.so foo.c
```

where foo.c consists of:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int i;
  printf("this is a silly test\n");

  if(i)
    goto ret;

  printf("hello world\n");

 ret:
 return 0;
}
```

Now, let's look at the objdump output, specifically that of foo's main:

```
0000000005ec <main>: 
 5ec:   55                      push   %rbp
 5ed:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 5f0:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
 5f4:   48 8d 3d 6b 00 00 00    lea    0x6b(%rip),%rdi        # 666 <_fini+0xe>
 5fb:   e8 00 ff ff ff          callq  500 <puts@plt>
 600:   83 7d fc 00             cmpl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
 604:   75 0e                   jne    614 <main+0x28>
 606:   48 8d 3d 65 00 00 00    lea    0x65(%rip),%rdi        # 672 <_fini+0x1a>
 60d:   e8 ee fe ff ff          callq  500 <puts@plt>
 612:   eb 01                   jmp    615 <main+0x29>
 614:   90                      nop
 615:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 61a:   c9                      leaveq 
 61b:   c3                      retq   
 61c:   90                      nop
 61d:   90                      nop
 61e:   90                      nop
 61f:   90                      nop
```

I can clearly see that calls to puts are being redirected to the PLT, as expected. However, what I don't understand are the instructions at 604 and 612. They are not relative to the IP, nor a call to the PLT. They use an absolute address, based on the 
symbol main.

How could this shared library then possibly be used simultaneously betwen several processes? It could (and should) be loaded at different virtual addresses, but the point is that each process should share the implementation stored in RAM. How can different processes with main loaded at different virtual addresses share the instructions at 604 and 612?

Comment: X86 opcodes `75` (hex) and `eb` are relative jumps, not absolute ones, and the operands in your listing demonstrate it.  The disassembly has perhaps confused you by giving the actual target addresses; look at the machine code instead.

Answer (score 0):

They're not absolute jumps, they're PC relative jumps.  In fact ALL direct jump and call instructions are PC-relative on x86 -- there are NO absolute direct jumps (so if you want an absolute jump, it has to be indirect).

The reason the callq instruction use the PLT is because the target symbol might be in a *different* shared object, so even a relative branch won't work (the other shared object might be loaded at any address, independently of this shared object).  The PLT itself is actually a small piece of code within the shared object, with a single (indirect) absolute jump for each remote symbol.  When the shared objects a dynamically loaded, the absolute address is set appropriately, so when the code runs, the callq instruction will be a pc-relative branch (call) to the PLT which consists of a single indirect jump to the puts routine.